# Debounce on function defined in an object cannot access object's context

Tags: javascript

I was trying to implement a debounce function which works fine if tied to global functions

```js
Function.prototype.debounce = function(debounceTime) {
  let timeoutIdentifier;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timeoutIdentifier);
    setTimeout(() => {
      this(args)
    }, debounceTime)
  }
}

var debouncedFunction = (function() {
  console.log('hi');
}).debounce(2000); // logs 'hi' after 2 seconds

debouncedFunction();
```

Unfortunately I am not able to make it work if used with a function defined as a property of an object

```
var obj = {
  name: 'saksham',
  printName: (() => {
    console.log(this.name)
  }).debounce(3000)
}

obj.printName(); // prints nothing
```

Tried binding the objects context to `printName()` as well but it did not work. Any possible solutions?

Comment: Why don't you just do `obj.name` instead of `this.name`?

Comment: What if I later want to do something like `obj.printName.call(anotherObject)`

Comment: Do you really want that? If so, please add this requirement to your question, because that rules out arrow functions (which do not act differently when called with `call`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular function to declare your object method, so it doesn't capture `this` context when it is declared (currently it's being assigned to `window`).
Also, use the [`Function.prototype.apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) in your debounce function in order to set the right `this` context in the method call:

```js
Function.prototype.debounce = function(debounceTime) {
  let timeoutIdentifier;
  const self = this;
  return function(...args) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutIdentifier);
    timeoutIdentifier = setTimeout(() => {
      self.apply(this, args)
    }, debounceTime)
  }
}

var obj = {
  name: 'saksham',
  printName: (function() {
    console.log(this.name)
  }).debounce(3000)
}

obj.printName(); // saksham
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't understand how your debounce function works ...

```
var obj = {
  name: 'saksham',
  printName: function () {
    console.log(this.name)
  }
}
obj.printName()
```

I think you cannot get the property name.

Change `() => {} by function () {}` to get it

When you do () => {} you delete the possibility to use `this`

Comment: You should write answers only when you're sure of you, while you don't have enough rep to comment